# how to change the color of the border line of listview in a list detail layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

how to change the color of the border line of listview in a list detail layout? It is always a black line that seperates listview and detailview in large screens (tablets). Not sure where it is set or how to set a new value. I want to change it to grey color.

This is my activity_items.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:showDividers="middle"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentItemsList"
        android:name="com.demo.ListFragment"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:color="#757872"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_items_list"
        />

    <View android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_width="1dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flDetailContainer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: its the one that says `View` you can clearly see the background is black

Comment: I tried to change the one in View. It doesn't change the color of listview seperator at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set black you will get black only. If you want grey color you need to set color as grey. Android can read what you have written in you code, can't read your mind.  :D

Do this

```
<View android:background="#BDBDBD"
    android:layout_width="1dp" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

To change the list view separator color do this

```
android:divider="#BDBDBD"
android:dividerHeight="1dp"
```

in your list view

Comment: lol, I tried to change the background color of view to grey. It didn't the color of the listview seperator :(

Comment: Please see my edit. You were asking for something else in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<View android:background="#000000"
```

Just change the code (000000) to match the color you want to use.